# iPad printing orientation problem

Tags: objective-c, ipad, printing, orientation, airprint

I have an printing problem in my ipad app.
The view which I want to print is in landscape mode, I want to print it in the portrait mode.

I have **HP B110A** printer which supports AirPrint

Following is my code for printing

```
NSData *dataFromPath = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController  sharedPrintController];

if(printController && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData:dataFromPath]) {
        printController.delegate = self;

    UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
    printInfo.jobName = [filePath lastPathComponent];
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexNone;
    printInfo.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientationPortrait;
    printController.printInfo = printInfo;
    printController.printingItem = dataFromPath;

    [printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];

        //and some handler code here
}
```

Now, even when I have set the print orientation as Portrait the print is appearing in landscape mode.

**PS: My app is set to work in landscape mode only.**

Comment: while presenting this printcontroller was this looked like with portrite or landscape mode